# Titillium Font is smaller when swap

Tags: webfonts

I am using titilium webfont from google fonts. For performance

```
 @font-face {
font-display:swap;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Titillium Web'),url('https://www.selltoneruk.co.uk/fonts/TitilliumWeb-Regular.eot'); 
}
```

I am using font display swap. This means, a local font will be used until webfont loaded. But titilium web font is a narrow font. So local font takes bigger place until font loads. When I refresh page text containing object seem bigger for a second then shows up normally. Is there a narrow local font? Or is there a way to show local font size with smaller px value?

Answer (score 0):

`font-display:swap;` is not the right solution to minimise the “flash of unstyled text” (FOUT). If you wish to avoid FOUT at all and only want the custom font to show when it is loaded then I would recommend to go with `font-display: optional;` It will still load a custom font in the background to be there for the next page load definitely. In addition, the browser will decide for you whether it should load the web font on slow connections or not.